# Anonymous functions in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell

Is it possible to create something analogous to an anonymous function whose value can be assigned to an array element and later called? I can't seem to find a way to do this in a bash script but perhaps there's a workaround.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Nooooooooooooo.

Complete answer: Functions in bash are not first-class objects, therefore there can be no such thing as an anonymous function in bash.

Comment: As a workaround, I'd define the functions with names and store just the names in the array; then just `eval` the array element when you want to call the function.

Comment: @choroba Perhaps you should post this as an answer. Even though it's not directly possible as Ignacio described, your workaround is a good idea.

Comment: Does the bash bug in CVE-2014-6271 [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/2hbxtc/cve20146271_remote_code_execution_through_bash/ckrhvtl) confirm that anonymous functions can exist in shell scripts?

Comment: @Lizz: No. It simply takes advantage of a flaw in one of the ways to create a function.

Comment: The full explanation is NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO! No way. Forget it. Don't even think about it.  Go away.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it doesn't have to be class or OO language, it has to be functional.

Comment: I am surprised it's the most upvoted and accepted answers. There are some ways to do that, those aren't native, but it's possible. So, the right answer would be - is it supported? no; is it possible? yep.

Answer (score 19):

It is possible; I wrote a library to do exactly this, though it's a very strange project. The source code is available at http://github.com/spencertipping/bash-lambda. Using this library:

```
$ my_array=()
$ my_array[0]=$(fn x 'echo $((x + 1))')
$ my_array[1]=$(fn x 'echo $((x + 2))')
$ ${my_array[0]} 5
6
$ ${my_array[1]} 5
7
$
```

The trick is to have the `fn` function create a file containing the body of the function, `chmod +x` that file, then return its name. This causes stray files to accumulate, which is why the library also implements an asynchronous mark/sweep garbage collector.

Comment: Is there a way to to wait for a command to finishing executing before executing the anonymous function?

Comment: @William Shell scripts are synchronous by default. If you run `some_command; ${my_array[0]} 5`, or `some_command && ${my_array[0]} 5`, both expressions will only run `"${my_array[0]} 5` after running `some_command`.

Answer (score 10):

If you really need array to store the functions, you can define named functions and store just their names. You can then call the function as `${array[n]}`. Or, you can name them `func1` .. `funcN` and then just call `func$n`.

Comment: bash has `declare -n reference_name` - not anonymous, but name can be abstracted, e.g.: `declare -n aref; a() { echo "function a"; }; aref=a` then `$aref` will execute `a`.

Comment: @JackWasey: Can you elaborate? I'm not getting the output back.

Comment: I mistyped. Try `echo ${!aref}`, then `${!aref}`

Answer (score 9):

The common technique is to assign function definitions conditionally:

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
a) foo() { echo case a; };;
b) foo() { echo case b; };;
*) foo() { echo default; } ;;
esac

foo
```

Answer (score 1):

well bash is turing complete, soo thats perfectly possible ;)

but aside from this its not really worth the consideration.

you could simulate such behaviour though with something along this line:

```
echo myval ; ( foocmd "$_" && barcmd "$_" )
```

but why?!?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was looking for how to do something analogous to

```js
[1,2,3,4,5].map(x => x*2).filter(x => x < 7);
```

i.e. Being able to manipulate previous results in a pipeline in a flexible way.

---

## xargs

A nice way I had heard of to handle this on the command line is through the `xargs` command.  My first impression was it wasn't very flexible

```bash
$ printf "one two\nthree\tfour" | xargs echo "args> "
# => args>  one two three four
$ printf "one two three four" | xargs echo "args> "
# => args>  one two three four
```

By default it splits standard input by any whitespace into separate arguments, then feeds those arguments to the command (it'll be clearer with the examples below)

I just learned **[from this extremely helpful gist Brainiarc7 wrote](https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/133fd582e124981c08cbafca98455ee9)** how xargs can be really flexible and useful.  **Definitely read/skim that, it's really good with more explanation**.  I included examples and things I gleaned from it below though, hopefully it's helpful.

### 1. `-n`: Split up args into `n`-sized chunks

```bash
# Chunk args into groups of two
$ printf "one two\nthree\tfour" | xargs -n 2 echo "args> "
# =>
# args>  one two
# args>  three four
```

Using `-n 1` will probably be very useful

### 2. `-I`: Interpolate args into a command using a placeholder

An example probably best illustrates how this one works.

```bash
# Indicate we want `%` to be the placeholder, split args into groups of two,
# then interpolate them in the command at the placeholder
printf 'one two three four' | xargs -I % -n 2 echo "Chunk of args> " % " <in the middle of a command"
# =>
# Chunk of args>  one two  <in the middle of a command
# Chunk of args>  three four  <in the middle of a command
```

You give `-I` the string you want to use as a placeholder.  The placeholder can be whatever text you like (e.g. `my_unique_placeholder`), but `%` is conventional.

### 3. `-0`: Chunk args by the null character (UTF+0000)

This isn't as convenient, but you can use it to split by an arbitrary character via `tr`.

```bash
# Split arg chunks by tab character:
$ printf 'one two\tthree\tfour' | tr '\t' "\0" | xargs -0 -n 1 echo "args> "
# =>
# args>  one two
# args>  three
# args>  four
```

### 4. `-L`: split args on `n` lines into a chunk

```bash
# Take all args on every 2 lines as a chunk
$ printf 'one two\nthree\nfour' | xargs -L 2 echo "args> "
# =>
# args>  one two three
# args>  four
```

---

https://gist.github.com/Brainiarc7/133fd582e124981c08cbafca98455ee9
https://shapeshed.com/unix-xargs/

Comment: Not sure that your example 2 is proving that with xargs, `({arg}) => {body}` is what's happening in your code?

Comment: You're right, that was a confusing explanation.  I was using `{}` similar to how a manpage would, but that doesn't make sense in a javascript context!  Hopefully the edit is clearer.

Comment: I was curious because that kind of implementation `(arg) => body` is what I was looking for. The edit makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Create the fn file in your `PATH`

```
#!/bin/sh

printusage () {
        printf "Create anonymous function, for example\n"
        printf "fn 'echo "$1 $2"'"
        exit 1
}


[ "$#" = "1" ] || printusage
fun=$1
[ "$fun" = "" ] && printusage
fun_file="$(mktemp /tmp/fun_XXXXXX)"

echo "#!/bin/sh" > "$fun_file"
echo "" >> "$fun_file"
echo "$fun" >> "$fun_file"
chmod u+x "$fun_file"

echo "$fun_file"
```

You can then do :

```
foo=$(fn 'echo $1')
${foo} "bar"
```