# Prevent pollution by variables in Bash include scripts

Tags: bash, posix, sh

If you introduce variable in Bash include scripts it will be available in original environment and possible conflict with  original environment.

Is it possible to prevent pollution on original environment?

From **virtualenv**-**bin/activate** and **/etc/bash_completion** scripts:

- I see **unset** and unique prefixes, like *_LIB*.
- Another way to wrap code in function and use non-POSIX **local** keyword. But function name can possibly conflict with original environment. I don't know how to create andinvoke anonymous function in Bash...

Comment: If your code is so complicated, switch to a real programming language.

Comment: Nothing like anonymous fucntion in bash... More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427955/anonymous-functions-in-shell-scripts)

Comment: @choroba I am writing script which turn Bash environment (PATH,
etc) but precomputation requires additional variables, which can conflict with already existing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it all depends on how you execute your script, if your goal is to indeed execute it and expand your environment, you have no much choice than using the `(` and `)` to fork a shell and have all variables executed within kept in its scope or using `unset` at the end of the bash script to remove all unwanted variables from the shell.

Otherwise, you can simply have your script executed "normally" throuh a fork, and then have all the variables are not getting out of the called's scope when giving back control to the calling shell.

In the end, you're not giving enough context to give a definite and precise answer to your question… other than just general advices.

Comment: Script used by **dot** or **source** command only. I think that it is possible to **echo** in subshell end **eval** in original shell as workaround... But uniq prefix is more elegant solution in restricted lang like Bash...

Comment: then I don't get what's troubling you… use your script's name as a prefix, which makes less likely to override anything existing. You could as well test for existing variables before using it, using the env command, just to be sure you're not stepping over something else. And of course, unset everything once you're done.